# Erase opencv rect objects from a vector

Tags: c++, object, opencv, erase, rect

I am using a vector of opencv Rect objects. What i want is to erase some of vectors elements inside a for-loop. However, it seems that I haven't access to vector's erase() fucntion. I am receiving the following message:

> /home/christosh/Desktop/recognition-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH_*System*_Release/../faceRec/src/Detection.cpp:88: error: 'class cv::Rect_' has no member named 'erase'

My code :

```
     vector<Rect> faces, eyes;
     for(int l=0; l<eyes.size(); l++){
        if(eyes[l].y> faces[i].height){
            eyes[l].erase;
        }
     }
```

Comment: you should delete from the vector, not from the rect. please try eyes.erase(eyes.begin() + 1);

Comment: yea definitely thanks!! I got your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you miss parenthesis? That's a function.

```
eyes[l].erase();
```

Edit: Seems I misread you question. If is is stl::vector erase then you can take hint from code below: You will have to use iterator.

> ```
> vector<int>::iterator it = res.begin();
> for( ; it != res.end(); it++)
> {
>     it = res.erase(it);
> }
> ```

Comment: this has another syntax error. erase is a member of std::vector class, not Rect.